# update internal library of pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have added third party library "FolioReaderKit" in my projet via cocoa pods.

This library contains "RealmSwift" in it but that's not updated to the latest version. Now I want to update the "RealmSwift" but I don't know how to do it.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FolioReaderKit` library has a fixed RealmSwift version on its [Podspec file](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReaderKit/blob/master/FolioReaderKit.podspec):

```
s.dependency 'RealmSwift', '3.17.3'
```

When you install it, this version is downloaded.

The only way you can change it is to create a copy of the library (can be local) and modify its Podspec file.

Comment: It would be changed back after every `pod install`, nope?

Comment: No, because you can specify the pod path on the Podfile with pod 'FolioReaderKit', :path => '../Path_To_Local_Pod_Folder'  if you use it local, or  pod 'FolioReaderKit', :git => 'https://github.com/FolioReaderKitCopy' if you copy the repository on GitHub. Either way the modified pod will be used on `pod install`, and the changes will not be lost.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad idea, because version compatibility of `FolioReaderKit` and `RealmSwift` might be broken. However, you can just add `RealmSwift` to your `Podfile` as independent pod it won't add it twice.